# Is it possible to get the file path of the current live set file in Max For Live?

Tags: max-msp-jitter, ableton-live

I am trying to save the contents of a ~buffer object into the current live set project. Is there a way to get the full file path of the Ableton Live set file *programmatically* without using an interactive dialog? I will use the set path to calculate the path of the new audio file and send it to the ~buffer with a "write" message.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the Live API will not give you the path to your Live set.

However, it looks like you want to load recorded audio clips into a buffer. Since Live 9, this can be done with the file_path property of a clip.

If you paste the code below into an empty audio device, it should automatically load the last clip you recorded on its track into a buffer:

```
----------begin_max5_patcher----------
1712.3oc6a0zrZaCEcM7qviW19xarjk+ftqsyzY5pl8YxvHvBPoBaO1hWdIY
R9sW8gse1.FK.mGhlrw.RxxGcz8dtWIr9xzItKxdlT557aNuyYxjuLcxDUQx
BlT86ItawOujgKUMyMk7wrEev8AcUbxybUwL5SjG4ankIjmnKI00uJKkWR+L
Q1Ff2idUEmtaa1NNivU8oeUo5h3eJmnAj6Bb5Z2Gbboo75ObdeUiyw7kanoq
mWPVx0sGNCHdBNAxKQyjWAwO50bGzDEREn+MAwsAXJdq5I596ETLy4OxXItu
.TZZMNAxx95zoxKObkzUFNYKorzojvcJwayYmGkA5ixNIAAfM7C..NIAE8ZQ
PeD+DYUVw1uU2iK1sZEon4Q1kb5xBg8wBqD7qxj4DegQKUeZ.i4KmFbfAgxO
BQ8PYg0frjvDc.MKcYFKqnpij2p2iQwwP+.427fQn.f7aAM8VGxLX7r1xKH4
jzDGwGL7xWCKsZWwX4033SZpEbi8E0FbeqxMTvDdNvyhhfCZFpDxLfuhgZeS
uSRXnaLgk6jsnjT7D4u9aF4sX9l+Y0aY3OIFQ+IilO1VWsbh7dLF4C7iTdRH
.HJT9MUQ9OHcwLfh88eT3+ABgmjhAWDE29gSJpH1JlUzUTF4IRQoPXnUqm3h
yyaU7jV2hb53C5AekTmrHZptHPSQEhXt02eTSo3BAEvEi+cEZ3+bbnqtRgIv
z5asgeTwEBUwMCiTVfg9sz5DFKqYYK+Whhl7pKLSnrPSEJLkjTNlWghlpSHq
v6X74crFfOdz5WI0l56l6NI3V2j0EzjrTIH5bmxhqebBwWcHuf1CFUKRw4G4
lKEiickKvERVcAizxGW3Ejkw5VUyDovYBmR2h4DNUCVnWSmR2lWnRfo0Chjh
E8wlxkEYLVmtRWySGoFc9Uejlv2n5q1Ton4z75o.2FNJgtlTx6VFGutraIcx
DrsQXaUhNkeJ0htJFbmENz10bbwg90VGN+vlY1db+Czwv8Cjt+9PkHPKu+8U
.lsOZ6WDnGs1I05sUNbWHqJyRDulbTZMuPX6Vv+jStV9cdIKiOmllPd9hHaP
aJrkGcaUTfl5D5D5zXTW5vh8qke54F.JV00Hj5Wg8O4.ulIG3HN4bBSd0Bhp
hSVL9l9cxbc.dMRE3K5fHd6SqnqhVaUQoHm9j4htTfj4XNuftXGWKtL4.Fch
67bY3uRNIUq+2397xTz2cOIQVLNxkuNWqu5rDmlkRWhYyywED45OuR+oK0qH
R6MDMnSQ7cfSQgfEHNxDglKY7apaQfNK6C2nf8IVvc.wJCvx99Ef0PJEgBMK
5JJ7dH75ZB+JsUGCA.TnJrnNw7SI.fhteBKJiLb6Xz3Hk.vfd9n3+eGQbPk5
kurd9aiHMBph6o24sSNUE7SUZC4T+Pfgpz92KpzWrc5XHm3Gq1RIT3fBzveJ
PalWuGzPAZueXEnq2SeZxsyvG4oxLYvEV5GaKBImfP+UGv3yjmwNSA7MSU1+
dHMuewAdKISP0d8OLYFdGPlel4rku4BMOGqLw7Apc7CEOjyNzZ1HBSxZPsko
k2LITXPjjUGd2cfQ2MauyURqikAKblJ8gXzf6uS7OW5fo5pPnYAo.A2AQ7sg
Tcg58eb3TcAveXS0UMOcw6Am+f5Img8uW0VGOXFu1h4upWc+dmuEpJXV80dW
u1rdGzsm.WlscKIs5erdDIC8Hre1vyn+2fv.yFrAd8OCeFC1WdkEXzz99G5U
nUV+wYgxrcEKqmVqrOc5B7DRIml17Bb7tWzw2qganIIcegIzuiAkx2XA86Fh
QSYmKjOBTNNlg1EjAF.YzAsy5grLdjkf4YFBY4JSrDHKWDuQFyyrFi4Yl59E
YMPFYHjk6BfsHYDaJMGaOXFZZzD6AylBYj0fXSML7sG2OSkLrGyBjorLvd79
LDwxzQsEmOSi9Armb4NRLhd7+rm3ePi0LrGOPeSwLxhD5Lc4THncgYiVahm0
j0Lx3n11iV2QfROX1dVpMxT8YjEE4NzT6Y6YUfHSiofrn0TY51vfFqEU479o
sOyRCs+0eYjNYQCexkNiiayQAwId388PWyxVfYUGvrl68HmpmouPhizg9isa
c1N92FmSFYIccpb317sgODtPO8qBn+oN3dvK4b6AGWVhld6HIPTzvjD3ZIIU
m1c6n0b19hIUL2AhHxyeuCrAa8rfkNqr4PwiCENNXN7rvimEgmHSvS3qGdBL
AOnWO7.LAOAuZ3wD3.eUQCv.z.t.znc826HKKAxdGU48NlxGdDk663IKdNec
5+kdwbrB
-----------end_max5_patcher-----------
```

Comment: That is an interesting piece of the pie. I wonder if there is a way to do the opposite? That is, save the contents of a buffer~ into a clip on the track?

Comment: It doesn't look like the ClipSlot object has a feature to load clips: http://cycling74.com/docs/max5/refpages/m4l-ref/m4l_live_object_model.html#ClipSlot, so I would say this is not possible at the moment. You can however save the path to a buffer you saved to disk as an audiofile in your live set with the `pattr` object. Perhaps that is more towards where you want to go? Could you explain more about what you are building?

Comment: I think pattr is the way to go here. Too bad there isn't a way to register the sample so it will work with Live's "Collect and Save" feature.

I have built an audio effect meant for live performance that allows you to record a note (or any sound) from a live instrument into one of 8 slots assigned to midi notes which come on from another device added to a midi track that sends them via max. I then use the "Midi Sequencer" device to send the notes and adjust the per-step chance values from a set of midi knobs.

The question above is about automatically saving the state of the device.

Comment: Yup, it would be great if it were possible to register newly created samples with collect all and save, that would be a great feature.